# POI: How to validate empty cells in a range

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm creating an Excel file where, once created and downloaded, a user isn't allowed to let empty cells in a specific column (*because he will send it again with information he entered*).

I'm using `POI HSSFDataValidation` with `setEmptyCellAllowed(false)`.

But when the user downloads the file, he still can leave empty cells (*after writing some text and deleting it*).

Any suggestions?

**Here's my code:**

```
HSSFDataValidation dv = new HSSFDataValidation();
dv.setFirstColumn((short)19);
    dv.setLastColumn((short)19);
    dv.setFirstRow((short)4);
    dv.setLastRow((short)24);
    dv.setDataValidationType(DVConstraint.ValidationType.INTEGER);
    dv.setOperator(DVConstraint.OperatorType.BETWEEN);
    dv.setDataValidationType(HSSFDataValidation.DATA_TYPE_INTEGER);
    dv.setOperator(HSSFDataValidation.OPERATOR_BETWEEN);
    dv.setFirstFormula("0");
    dv.setSecondFormula("1000");
    //dv.setEmptyCellAllowed(true);
    dv.setEmptyCellAllowed(false);
    dv.setShowPromptBox(true);
    dv.setSurppressDropDownArrow(false);
    dv.setErrorStyle(HSSFDataValidation.ERROR_STYLE_STOP);
    //dv.createErrorBox("", "");
    //dv.createPromptBox("", "");
    sheet.addValidationData(dv);
```

Comment: How do you plan on "validating" a cell that the user never visits?  I believe your only true guarantee that all the cells are not empty is to do the validation on the server after the user submits it.  Not much different than a web form, you can't rely entirely on client-side validation.

Comment: at first, the cells are filled. But the user can delete the contents of those cells and then leave them blank. What I look for is a validation that asks the user to write some text.

Comment: What exactly constitutes a valid entry?  What if the user enters "." or "###" or any other nonsense as the full text?  I don't think Excel is the right tool for the job here, however I will defer to someone who has used it in this capacity.

Comment: the cells must have integers values and that validation already works fine.

Answer (score 0):

this is not answering your question directly but you can use a try and catch block to write something in the cell yourself if the user has kept it blank: